# Vue 3: Mount component onto existing app instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I have a plugin written in Vue 2 that programmatically mounts a component onto existing app instance.

```
export default {
  install (Vue) {
    const component = new (Vue.extend(Component))()
    const vm = component.$mount()
    document.body.appendChild(vm.$el)
  }
}
```

Trying to migrate this to Vue 3 and this is the closest I've got.

```
export default {
  install (app) {
    const component = defineComponent(Component)
    const container = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(container)
    const vm = createApp(component).mount(container)
  }
}
```

The problem is that createApp creates a new app instance, while Vue.extend created only a subclass. I need to have all globally available components in the main app, available in plugin's component as well. Creating a new app instance prevents this.

Component needs to be programatically mounted. Manually inserting it into template is not an option.

Please help.

Comment: Consider explaining your case. Should it really be a plugin? Probably you need a teleport/portal instead of low-level things. There wasn't a teleport in V2

Comment: Not looking for teleport functionality. It's a plugin to avoid confusion as to where should the component be placed in structure. Also to avoid potential bugs with misuse of component. This way the plugin creates the component, places it onto root level and exposes a few methods (not included in snippet as it's not relevant to the issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem! There is a [discussion on the Vue GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/1802) and they created a module that you can use: [mount-vue-component](https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component). I found it very helpful to look at [the module's code](https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component/blob/4170215023fcb2c58f34ded6ca2e0b72ff9e6c33/index.js), it does exactly what you want to do.

To instantiate the component, you have to create a VNode, which you can do with `createVNode()` (which is the same as [`h()`](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#h)). To get access to the app's context, including global components, you have to set the `appContext` property. Finally, the `render()` function mounts the component instance to an HTML Element.

So for you example, that gives you:

```
export default {
  install (app) {
    const container = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(container)

    const vNode = createVNode(component)
    vNode.appContext = app._context
    render(vNode, container)
  }
}
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, createVNode, ref, render  } = Vue;

const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      msg: ref('Hello from app!')
    }  
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)

app.component('inner-component', {
  template:  '<div style="color: green;">This is a global component in app</div>'
})
app.mount('#app')


const component = {
  props: ['color'],
  template: '<span :style="{color: color}">Hello from mounted component!</span><inner-component></inner-component>'
}
const el = document.getElementById('leComponent')
const vNode = createVNode(component, {color: 'blue'}, [])
vNode.appContext = app._context
render(vNode, el)
```

```css
div{
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{msg}}
  <inner-component></inner-component>
</div>
<div id="leComponent"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's great! Please consider marking it as accepted answer and/or leave an upvote - it's a bit silly, but it is how the site works

Comment: Need more reputation for upvoting, but I did mark it as accepted answer.